# Javascript not firing on second 'process' page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am running a contact form on page1.php. When the form is submitted, the data goes to page2.php to be processed.

The problem that i am encountering is that Javascript on page2.php is not firing although this is the same template as page1.php.

There are three issues:

1) I am using JS to populate a datepicker box with today's date. That is not executing on page2.php

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#wo_selecteddate').datepicker({dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"});
    $('#wo_selecteddate').datepicker('setDate', 'today');
    });
</script>
```

2. The "check availability" button that goes with the datepicker does not appear on page2.php and this is driven by another JS which is called from http://welcome-online.net/responsive/js/wo.min.js.
3. The hamburger menu for the mobile version is an off-canvass menu and works well except on page2.php when the entire menu displays. That's called from https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.mmenu/5.3.4/js/jquery.mmenu.min.js. To activate it, is the script below.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#my-menu").mmenu({
         slidingSubmenus: false
      });
      var API = $("#my-menu").data( "mmenu" );
      
      $("#my-button").click(function() {
         API.open();
      });
   });
</script>
```

Why is JS not firing on this second page that is processing the data?

Thanks

Comment: Try fixing 1 by 1. Since JS is special, if one line doesn't work, the rest will stop working :). Try changing the 2nd js into something simple like alert("123") to see if it's working :)

Comment: Look at your JavaScript console in your browser, you should see the error that you are encountering displayed there.

Comment: if page2.php is loaded by full page refresh, there is a great chance to lose the data. In that case, try to set the data in cookie/session and retrieve the data from it. Another way is pass this data as query parameter to the second page.

Comment: @Tree Ngyuen I've removed the datepicker from page2.php as it's not really a navigation page that someone would select. However, the hamburger menu script is misbehaving.

Comment: @Chris ... tough one as this is occuring only on mobile devices and not desktop. I know there is a way to connect phone through desktop to debug but never set up for that.

Comment: @cobra Yes, page2.php is a full page refresh just as if you were loading a new page ... but it is not behaving like a new page and that's the problem. The php form data is carrying over from page1.php which is important. There are not JS stickies that I need to move over ... but a thought just came to mind ... which I will experient with. Will test and come back.